# Creating JSON string using two PySpark columns by GroupBy

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I have a Spark dataframe as below. I want to create a column 'new_col' which groups by all of the columns except 'Code' and 'Department' and assign a JSON structure based on columns 'Code' and 'Department'.

The dataframe needs to be sorted first. Rows 1-3 and 4-5 are duplicated except for columns Code and Department. So I would have JSON created for 1st 3 rows as new_col as {"Code": "A", "Department": "Department Store"}, { "Code": "B","Department": "All Other Suppliers"}, {"Code": "C","Department": "Rest"}

My input dataframe:

[image]

Expected output Spark dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('XYZ', '324 NW', 'VA', 'A', 'Department Store', 'X', 'Y'),
     ('XYZ', '324 NW', 'VA', 'B', 'All Other Suppliers', 'X', 'Y'),
     ('XYZ', '324 NW', 'VA', 'C', 'Rest', 'X', 'Y'),
     ('ABC', '45 N Ave', 'MA', 'C', 'Rest', 'A', 'A'),
     ('ABC', '45 N Ave', 'MA', 'B', 'All Other Suppliers', 'A', 'A'),
     ('ZXC', '12 SW Street', 'NY', 'A', 'Department Store', 'B', 'Z')],
    ['Name', 'Address', 'State', 'Code', 'Department', 'col1', 'col2']
)

cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ['Code', 'Department']]
w1 = W.partitionBy(cols).orderBy('Code')
w2 = W.partitionBy(cols).orderBy(F.desc('Code'))
df = (df
      .withColumn('_rn', F.row_number().over(w1))
      .withColumn('new_col', F.collect_list(F.to_json(F.struct(['Code', 'Department']))).over(w2))
      .withColumn("new_col", F.array_join("new_col", ","))
      .filter('_rn=1')
      .drop('_rn')
)
```

```py
df.show(truncate=False)
# +----+------------+-----+----+-------------------+----+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |Name|Address     |State|Code|Department         |col1|col2|new_col                                                                                                                      |
# +----+------------+-----+----+-------------------+----+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |ABC |45 N Ave    |MA   |B   |All Other Suppliers|A   |A   |{"Code":"C","Department":"Rest"},{"Code":"B","Department":"All Other Suppliers"}                                             |
# |XYZ |324 NW      |VA   |A   |Department Store   |X   |Y   |{"Code":"C","Department":"Rest"},{"Code":"B","Department":"All Other Suppliers"},{"Code":"A","Department":"Department Store"}|
# |ZXC |12 SW Street|NY   |A   |Department Store   |B   |Z   |{"Code":"A","Department":"Department Store"}                                                                                 |
# +----+------------+-----+----+-------------------+----+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In groupby, I don't want to hardcode those columns ('Name', 'Address', 'State', 'col1', 'col2') as I might have many more columns. Also, I want to keep Code and Department in my final dataframe.

Comment: How do you decide which row from Code and Department goes into your result? There are several of those rows and you want to show just one. How to choose?

Comment: I want to sort by code and keep the 1st row of each group

Comment: You previous output gave the right value for new_col where we were capturing all the Code and departments for each group, all I wanted was adding code and department columns as well, now you current output does have those two columns but the new_column is only capturing code and department for that particular row. I have attached my expected result dataframe as well

Comment: Also, I don't want those json elements in a list. It should be like {"Code":"C","Department":"Rest"}, {"Code":"B","Department":"All Other Suppliers"} not [{"Code":"C","Department":"Rest"}, {"Code":"B","Department":"All Other Suppliers"} ]

Comment: I added df.withColumn("new_col", array_join("new_col", ",")). It worked

Comment: @Shanoo - Nice improvement. I have added it to the answer and updated the resulting dataframe